# Transfering a value from a text input to a select input via submit() and vice versa

Tags: javascript, php, html, submit, onchange

I have an array with 3 values. First I display them with 3 hyperlinks. When the user clicks on a link, he receives a select input with the 3 options/values (preselected option is the hyperlink's value) and a text input (its value is also the hyperlink's value). After this, I want to transfer the value of a new selected option to the text input and if I write a value (which is equal to one value of the array) on the text input, then I want this option to be selected.

For example: I choose the hyperlink "maria". The text has the value "maria" and the select has also selected the option "maria".Then I select the option "anna". I expect to see the value "anna" on the text. Then I type "jana" and I also expect to see the option "jana" be selected.

The problem is that the text doesn't keep its value after its submit.

I used twice `onchange='submit()'` and I think there is the problem.
Here is what I did so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

  echo"<form method='post' action='".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."'>";

    $user_name = $_REQUEST['user_name'];
        if($_POST['username']){
                $user_name=$_POST['username'];
            }
            if($_POST['users']){
                $user_name=$_POST['users'];
            }
        if(!$user_name){    
            $users_array=['maria','anna','jana'];


    foreach($users_array as $us_name){
                echo "<a href='".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."?user_name=".$us_name." '> ".$us_name."</a><br/>";
                }   

        }else{      

            echo $user_name." ";
            echo $_POST['username']." ";
        if($_POST['username']){
                $user_name=$_POST['username'];

            }

            echo $_POST['users'];
        if($_POST['users']){
                $user_name=$_POST['users'];
            }




            echo"<input type='text' id='username' name='username' value='".$user_name."' onchange='submit()' />";
echo"<br><br><br><select id='users' name='users' onchange='submit()'>";

$users_array=['maria','anna','jana'];
        foreach($users_array as $auxvar_user_name)
                                                {
                                                    echo "<option value='".$auxvar_user_name."'"; 
                                                    if($_POST['username'] == $auxvar_user_name)
                                                        {
                                                            echo" selected='selected'";
                                                        } 
                                                    echo">".$auxvar_user_name."</option>";
                                                }

            echo "</select></form>";
        }
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The on change is a javascript (client side), where as your whole form is built in php(server side), its not compatible the way you are using them.

Comment: can I make it without onchange?

Comment: I don't want to use a submit button. The problem is, how can I make the text input to follow the select input and at the same time how can I make the select input follow the text input? There is a reaction everytime that I change something on the same element. How can I isolate this reaction?